# Segmentation Fault when accessing string array modified by a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

In my main, I define a pointer to an array of filename strings (that are to be determined):
`char **commands = NULL;`
I then call a function which populates the array based on `argc` & `argv` using `getopt()`.  Before I return from the function, I print the list of files in the array and it works fine.

Back in my main, I attempt to print the same list (as confirmation) but I get a segmentation error which I can't figure out how to fix.  I've included my code below.

Can someone please help me understand why `commands` in my main is not able to access the file list.

Cheers,
Nap

Here is the function that builds the list of file names:

```
int getInput (int argc, char **argv, const char *optionList, int *number, int *showEnds, char **commands, int *numberCommands) {

    char c;
    opterr = 0; // Turn off automatic error messages.
    while ( (c = getopt(argc, argv, optionList)) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'n':
                *number = TRUE;
                break;
            case 'E':
                *showEnds = TRUE;
                break;
            case '?':
                printf("Invalid switch used \"%c\"\n", optopt);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Input error occurred");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    printf("optind = %d,%d\n",optind, argc);

    commands = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc-1));

    if (optind < argc) {
        *numberCommands = (argc - optind);
        int ndx = 1;
        while (optind < argc) {
            int arraySize = (ndx+1)*sizeof(char*);
            commands = realloc (commands,arraySize);
            if (commands == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"Realloc unsuccessful");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            int stringSize = strlen(argv[optind])+1;
        commands[ndx] = malloc(stringSize);
            if(commands[ndx]==NULL){
                fprintf(stderr,"Malloc unsuccessful");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            strcpy(commands[ndx],argv[optind]);
            ndx++;
            optind++;
        }
        printf ("Done With Input\n");
        for (int i=1; i<=*numberCommands; i++) {
            printf ("%s\n",commands[i]);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *myInput;
    FILE *myOutput;
    int result;
    const char availOptions[] = "nE";

    // Option flags
    int number = FALSE;     // (Option n) number all output lines
    int showEnds = FALSE;   // (Option E) Show Ends

    char **commands = NULL;
    int numberCommands = 0;

    // Set default to stdin/stdout.
    myInput = stdin;
    myOutput = stdout;
    if (argc > 1) {
        result = getInput(argc,argv, availOptions, &number, &showEnds, commands, &numberCommands);
        if (result != EXIT_SUCCESS) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    printf ("Number of files = %d\n", numberCommands);
    for (int i=1; i<=numberCommands; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n",commands[i]);
    }

    echoInput(myInput, myOutput);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in a copy of the double-pointer

```
char **commands;
```

into the function. When you `malloc()` memory for it, it's not updating the pointer in your main function, only your local copy of the double-pointer. Hence, you're attempting to deference a NULL pointer in main. You could instead pass in a pointer to the double-pointer (i.e. the function would take a triple-pointer), your code would work then.

You would need to dereference the triple-pointer inside the function like so:

```
*commands = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc-1));
```

Alternatively, make a new double-pointer inside your function, do your work (leaving the code in your function roughly as-is) and before you return, assign the memory back into the pointer passed in from main:

```
*commands = local_commands;
```

Comment: Good call, using a local variable to clarify what's going on!  
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In this function:

```
int getInput (/* ... */, char **commands, int *numberCommands) {

    /* ... */
    commands = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc-1));
}
```

you accept a pointer-to-pointer-to-char parameter *by value*. Looking at the call site, we can see that value will always be `(char**)NULL`. The parameter is a *local variable* inside your function. Even though you change it, and even though the caller happens to have a variable with the same name, you never change the caller's copy.

If you want to change the caller's copy of `commands`, you need to pass the *address of that variable* to your function:

```
int getInput (/* ... */, char ***commands, int *numberCommands) {

    /* ... */
    *commands = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc-1));
}
```

Now the call site looks like this:

```
char **commands = NULL;
int numberCommands = 0;
/* ... */
if (argc > 1) {
    result = getInput(/*...*/, &commands, &numberCommands);
    if (result != EXIT_SUCCESS) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

note that `commands` and `numberCommands` are the two *out-parameters* - that is, they're the parameters where the function should change your local variable - so you're using `&` to pass pointers to both of them.

Comment: Thanks!! I flagged the other as my answer because of the suggestion to rename the variable locally, thus making it easier to read and understand.